# Joining Two Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two select queries to use in my project for getting data and displaying it in my web page. I want to join them so that I need to access data only once. But I don't know how to join them as one of the query contains group function. Could you help me? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to do the job in several steps. Before joining the result set to the query, you'll need to save it in a temporary table or table variable. (A temporary table may be preferable if you are expecting a large result set.)

Basically, your query would change to something like this:

```
/* prepare the storage */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sp_results') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #sp_results;
CREATE TABLE #sp_results (
  /* the types may be wrong, please modify as necessary */
  currency_cd int,
  salary decimal(10,2)
);

/* save the results of the SP */
INSERT INTO #sp_results
EXEC SP_name arguments…

/* use the saved results in your query */
SELECT
  your present columns,
  tmp.currency_cd,
  tmp.salary
FROM
  your present joins
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #sp_results AS tmp ON a proper join condition
;
```

The problem is, though, your SP is designed to return results for an *individual* employee while the query seems to be retrieving data for *multiple* employees. To resolve the issue, you could add an `employee_code` column to the temporary table and get/save the results for every employee one by one, in a cursor, using a loop.

But that would probably be one of the *worst* examples of using a cursor. A better alternative might be to create a view returning the same data as your SP, but for *all* employees:

```
CREATE VIEW employees_compensation_view
AS
SELECT
  employee_code,
  currency_cd,
  SUM(comprate) AS salary
FROM employees_compensation
GROUP BY
  employee_code,
  currency_cd
```

You would then be able just to join the view to your query, like this:

```
SELECT
  your present columns,
  ecv.currency_cd,
  ecv.salary
FROM
  your present joins
  LEFT OUTER JOIN employees_compensation_view AS ecv
    ON b.employee_code = ecv.employee_code
;
```

For better encapsulation of your business logic, you could also change the stored procedure query like this:

```
SELECT
  currency_cd,
  salary
FROM employees_compensation_view
WHERE employee_code = @emp_code
```

That is, if you still needed that SP.

Comment: Thanks. I created the employees_compensation_view and joined it to my query.